# Delete row if folder name not exists in server

Tags: php, mysql, delete-row

I want to delete mysql database row if subfolder name in folder'files/' not exists in server

```
mysql database

id  username   folder_name
1   namenlos   sssgggdddd   
2   megi       terf4vnvsd
3   mike       12gdf23124
.
.


directory:

server directory: 'files/'
                         terf4vnvsd    //subfolder name 'files'
                         12gdf23124    //subfolder name 'files'
```

but  folder `sssgggdddd` does not exist.

How I can get to delete row with `sssgggdddd` if folder name is not exists in folder `files`?

Comment: I don't have idee how I can get it

Comment: You can start by reading docs and try something.

Comment: I don't know how can I check folder name if exists or not

Comment: I am starting thank's for support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over all of the folder names in php, and do a check against them using [is_dir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php):

```
if (!is_dir('files/' . $foldername_name)) {
  DELETE FROM table_name WHERE folder_name = $folder_name
}
```